# Join on Two Tables With Matching id field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In the `form` table I have the following fields :

- id - PK auto incrementing
- username - stored as a session when the user logs in
- name
- species
- population
- weight
- length

In the `images` table I have the following fields :

- id - PK auto incrementing
- username - stored as a session when the user logs in
- path - path to the image

`$forms` - For storing data entered in a form. Has auto incrementing id field

`$images` - For storing the path to an image uploaded from the form. Has auto incrementing id field

Both the form data and image data are submitted at the same time and have matching ids. e.g.

- The id for the `form` data for `Tiger` in `$forms` is `1`
- The id for the `image` path for `Tiger` in `$images` is `1`

etc, etc.

If I run this query in MySQL admin the records and images match :

```
Select * from $forms JOIN $images ON $forms.id = $images.id
```

The problem is I have two queries in my php. One for retrieving and displaying the form data and one for retrieving and displaying the images e.g.

```
$Link = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password, $Database);
$Query = " Select * from $forms JOIN $images ON $forms.id = $images.id";
if($Result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
{
php for storing image path as array etc, etc
}

$Link = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password, $Database);
$Query = " Select * from $forms JOIN $images ON $forms.id = $images.id";
if($Result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
{
php for storing form data as arrays and adding a count etc, etc
}
```

So when I try the joins above it's a mess and the form data does not match with the image.

What query do I need to run in order to get the records to match? I have tried the same select statement in both queries and also tried reversing the order of the tables in the second query.

Comment: Do you have any column called Images.id in your forms table OR formID column in Images table ??? I think you are joining tables on wrong fields

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use `SELECT *` in software. Instead, enumerate the columns you need. For example, `SELECT forms.id, forms.image, forms.whatever`

Comment: M.Ali I have updated and listed the fields. Hope that helps

Comment: Ollie Jones Will it make a difference in this case? I have many fields in the form table. None of them are redundant apart from the username field which isn't displayed in any case.

Comment: You have NO connections between form and images, you need to add to images formId and attribute the form id so you know what to retrieve apart from their one primary auto incremented id's.

Comment: Prix I don't follow? Wouldn't formid be the same as id?

Comment: Your database is not normalized.

Comment: @Nullbreaker no, formid would be a field on the images table that would connect that given form to the image. The 2 id's you currently have DO not connect the 2 together. Here is an example, you create a new entry on the table forms with id 1 and you insert 5 new images to that form, on the images table and they will all have a primary auto increment id and also a secondary field called formid that will have the formid 1 so you can connect the 2 together.

Comment: Hi all, why we cannot use the username field?"Select * from $forms JOIN $images ON $forms.Username = $images.Username". This is a question.thx in advance

Comment: cyan The reason you cannot join on the username is that a user can created many different records. Each form and each image must be linked but also have unique identities e.g. record 1, record 2 etc, etc. The username field is stored so that a user can edit their records once they log in.

I am going to create a session from the id field in the form table and write that as the id in the image table, maybe that will preserve the links between the form and images.